# How to combine 2 csv files(each csv file having more than 100 columns and 425 & 7222 rows respectively) using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, merge

I have used pandas library to combine two csv files using pandas but i am not 
getting  desired result.In out.csv i m getting only column names.It seems like dropna function is not working after seeing Code 3 and Code 4.Please suggest me how should do it.First it was showing error dtype and low_memory so i used low_memory=false.After that also i am not getting right answer.

Code1:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv("true.csv",low_memory=False)
b = pd.read_csv("false.csv",low_memory=False)
#print b
#a=a.dropna(axis=1,how="all")
b = b.dropna(axis=1,how="all")
#print a
merged = a.merge(b, on='Name')
merged.to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
```

Output1:

[out.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoLxL.png)

**CMD** shows no error

Code 2:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv("true.csv",low_memory=False)
b = pd.read_csv("false.csv",low_memory=False)
#print b
a=a.dropna(axis=1,how="all")
b = b.dropna(axis=1,how="all")
#print a
merged = a.merge(b, on='Name')
merged.to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
```

Same out.csv

**CMD** shows no error

Code 3:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv("true.csv",low_memory=False)
b = pd.read_csv("false.csv",low_memory=False)
print b
a=a.dropna(axis=1,how="all")
b = b.dropna(axis=1,how="all")
#print a
merged = a.merge(b, on='Name')
merged.to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
```

same out.csv

**CMD** output

```
                 Name  nAcid   ALogP     ALogp2       AMR        apol  \
0     NCGC00090868-05      0  2.5092   6.296085   24.6331   11.087793
1     NCGC00258574-01      0  0.8580   0.736164   41.2286   25.019102
2     NCGC00256074-01      0 -1.2663   1.603516   29.8524   20.967516
3     NCGC00255887-01      0 -3.8723  14.994707   63.0584   48.122204
4     NCGC00257684-01      0  0.3201   0.102464   19.9881   15.227930
5     NCGC00255836-01      0  0.1835   0.033672   74.3973   37.687516
6     NCGC00255339-01      0  0.6030   0.363609   79.6663   44.210274
7     NCGC00254895-01      0 -0.0924   0.008538   50.8863   26.247516
8     NCGC00256627-01      0  1.6628   2.764904   50.8229   27.737102
9     NCGC00257445-01      0 -0.4644   0.215667   46.3842   24.281516
10    NCGC00256994-01      0  3.2104  10.306668   53.1445   30.028688
11    NCGC00256081-01      0 -0.1228   0.015080   43.5826   25.885516
12    NCGC00159473-05      0  2.1059   4.434815   62.4027   37.406481
13    NCGC00258886-01      0  0.5738   0.329246   24.9723   13.362758
14    NCGC00260536-01      0  1.5363   2.360218   91.9810   49.983860
15    NCGC00259214-01      0 -2.0207   4.083228   58.4309   40.459860
16    NCGC00254775-01      0  1.0180   1.036324   92.7307   47.861860
17    NCGC00257097-01      0 -0.8815   0.777042   44.2151   32.539860
18    NCGC00255059-01      0  0.8289   0.687075   54.5365   29.737516
19    NCGC00258829-01      0  0.6531   0.426540   38.7876   22.267930
20    NCGC00254435-01      0 -1.7996   3.238560   51.4988   41.589446
21    NCGC00256760-01      0 -1.9832   3.933082   37.0772   30.942653
22    NCGC00255967-01      1     NaN        NaN       NaN   21.685516
23    NCGC00094572-12      0  3.2214  10.377418  100.9937   52.076239
24    NCGC00256955-01      0  1.1604   1.346528   30.5714   16.447965
25    NCGC00258571-01      0 -0.4011   0.160881   46.3328   26.965516
26    NCGC00018221-08      1  1.7889   3.200163   81.6449   38.198723
27    NCGC00257404-01      0  0.4681   0.219118   48.5267   25.783516
28    NCGC00024595-08      0  0.9066   0.821924   97.5488   59.376583
29    NCGC00095099-05      3 -2.8747   8.263900  165.3811   92.940134
...               ...    ...     ...        ...       ...         ...
7692  NCGC00024309-17      0  1.1271   1.270354  123.3780   64.364618
7693  NCGC00092377-04      0  1.2781   1.633540  127.4281   65.573446
7694  NCGC00249894-01      2  0.9889   0.977923   93.7563   48.803895
7695  NCGC00258493-01      0  3.6334  13.201596   60.1071   25.220379
7696  NCGC00092328-02      1  0.9264   0.858217  117.7120   63.380618
7697  NCGC00015496-08      0 -3.4028  11.579048   55.2510   43.323790
7698  NCGC00255845-01      0     NaN        NaN       NaN  197.835924
7699  NCGC00255892-01      0  0.4437   0.196870   77.3472   40.541895
7700  NCGC00257628-01      0  2.3992   5.756161   30.7638   13.573586
7701  NCGC00095795-06      0  1.7370   3.017169   62.7555   28.529551
7702  NCGC00259502-01      0  1.7456   3.047119   67.2834   32.485516
7703  NCGC00254185-01      0  1.9464   3.788473   46.7099   19.902379
7704  NCGC00254078-01      0  1.9464   3.788473   46.7099   19.902379
7705  NCGC00259798-01      0  0.7592   0.576385   30.1050   14.373965
7706  NCGC00255984-01      0  4.3541  18.958187   97.1672   47.655895
7707  NCGC00258735-01      0  2.2459   5.044067   86.0636   43.796688
7708  NCGC00257478-01      0  5.1368  26.386714   95.2848   52.536618
7709  NCGC00163355-05      0 -0.2722   0.074093   84.3928   38.631930
7710  NCGC00254263-01      0     NaN        NaN       NaN   47.128758
7711  NCGC00260266-01      0  0.9368   0.877594   35.3574   21.567930
7712  NCGC00258239-01      0  2.3709   5.621167   75.0245   37.339102
7713  NCGC00257750-01      0  0.5695   0.324330   49.8130   25.248758
7714  NCGC00256348-01      0  0.2874   0.082599   41.9237   19.847551
7715  NCGC00254098-01      0  1.5354   2.357453   61.0800   33.663102
7716  NCGC00015563-13      0  1.6130   2.601769   97.3830   51.643032
7717  NCGC00258606-01      0  0.8041   0.646577   26.4598   15.491551
7718  NCGC00254798-01      0 -1.2646   1.599213   86.3007   41.545516
7719  NCGC00092310-06      0 -1.8789   3.530265   96.8643   57.331411
7720  NCGC00022043-06      0  0.6243   0.389750  102.7615   65.025376
7721  NCGC00257951-01      0 -0.2697   0.072738  142.9587   88.813306

      naAromAtom  nAromBond  nAtom  nHeavyAtom ...  P1s  P2s  E1s  E2s  E3s  \
0              0          0      8           7 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1              0          0     24          10 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2              0          0     21           9 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3              0          0     48          20 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
4              0          0     15           5 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5              0          0     32          20 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
6              0          0     38          20 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7              0          0     24          12 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
8              0          0     25          11 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
9              0          0     22          10 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
10             0          0     27          11 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
11             0          0     24          12 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
12             0          0     34          17 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
13             0          0     12           6 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
14             0          0     43          23 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
15             0          0     38          18 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
16             0          0     42          22 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
17             0          0     32          12 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
18             0          0     24          12 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
19             0          0     19           9 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
20             0          0     36          14 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
21             0          0     31          10 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
22             0          0     21           9 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
23             0          0     45          22 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
24             0          0     12           7 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
25             0          0     24          12 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
26             0          0     30          19 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
27             0          0     22          10 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
28             0          0     55          24 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
29             0          0     84          46 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
...          ...        ...    ...         ... ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...
7692           0          0     55          29 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7693           0          0     53          31 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7694           0          0     40          25 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7695           0          0     15          12 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7696           0          0     54          28 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7697           0          0     44          14 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7698           0          0    151          83 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7699           0          0     33          18 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7700           0          0      8           6 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7701           0          0     21          14 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7702           0          0     27          15 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7703           0          0     13          10 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7704           0          0     13          10 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7705           0          0     11           6 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7706           0          0     34          19 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7707           0          0     37          21 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7708           0          0     46          20 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7709           0          0     30          20 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7710           0          0     20          14 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7711           0          0     17           7 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7712           0          0     31          17 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7713           0          0     21          15 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7714           0          0     16           9 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7715           0          0     30          16 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7716           0          0     45          21 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7717           0          0     14           7 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7718           0          0     33          21 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7719           0          0     52          25 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7720           0          0     59          27 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7721           0          0     79          37 ...  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN

      Ts  As  Vs  Ks  Ds
0    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
3    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
4    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
5    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
6    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
8    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
9    NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
10   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
11   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
12   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
13   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
14   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
15   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
16   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
17   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
18   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
19   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
20   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
21   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
22   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
23   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
24   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
25   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
26   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
27   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
28   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
29   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
...   ..  ..  ..  ..  ..
7692 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7693 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7694 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7695 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7696 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7697 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7698 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7699 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7700 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7701 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7702 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7703 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7704 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7705 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7706 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7707 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7708 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7709 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7710 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7711 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7712 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7713 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7714 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7715 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7716 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7717 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7718 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7719 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7720 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
7721 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN

[7722 rows x 1876 columns]
```

Code 4:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.read_csv("true.csv",low_memory=False)
b = pd.read_csv("false.csv",low_memory=False)
#print b
a=a.dropna(axis=1,how="all")
b = b.dropna(axis=1,how="all")
print b
merged = a.merge(b, on='Name')
merged.to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
```

same out.csv

**CMD** output

```
                 Name  nAcid   ALogP     ALogp2       AMR        apol  \
0     NCGC00090868-05      0  2.5092   6.296085   24.6331   11.087793
1     NCGC00258574-01      0  0.8580   0.736164   41.2286   25.019102
2     NCGC00256074-01      0 -1.2663   1.603516   29.8524   20.967516
3     NCGC00255887-01      0 -3.8723  14.994707   63.0584   48.122204
4     NCGC00257684-01      0  0.3201   0.102464   19.9881   15.227930
5     NCGC00255836-01      0  0.1835   0.033672   74.3973   37.687516
6     NCGC00255339-01      0  0.6030   0.363609   79.6663   44.210274
7     NCGC00254895-01      0 -0.0924   0.008538   50.8863   26.247516
8     NCGC00256627-01      0  1.6628   2.764904   50.8229   27.737102
9     NCGC00257445-01      0 -0.4644   0.215667   46.3842   24.281516
10    NCGC00256994-01      0  3.2104  10.306668   53.1445   30.028688
11    NCGC00256081-01      0 -0.1228   0.015080   43.5826   25.885516
12    NCGC00159473-05      0  2.1059   4.434815   62.4027   37.406481
13    NCGC00258886-01      0  0.5738   0.329246   24.9723   13.362758
14    NCGC00260536-01      0  1.5363   2.360218   91.9810   49.983860
15    NCGC00259214-01      0 -2.0207   4.083228   58.4309   40.459860
16    NCGC00254775-01      0  1.0180   1.036324   92.7307   47.861860
17    NCGC00257097-01      0 -0.8815   0.777042   44.2151   32.539860
18    NCGC00255059-01      0  0.8289   0.687075   54.5365   29.737516
19    NCGC00258829-01      0  0.6531   0.426540   38.7876   22.267930
20    NCGC00254435-01      0 -1.7996   3.238560   51.4988   41.589446
21    NCGC00256760-01      0 -1.9832   3.933082   37.0772   30.942653
22    NCGC00255967-01      1     NaN        NaN       NaN   21.685516
23    NCGC00094572-12      0  3.2214  10.377418  100.9937   52.076239
24    NCGC00256955-01      0  1.1604   1.346528   30.5714   16.447965
25    NCGC00258571-01      0 -0.4011   0.160881   46.3328   26.965516
26    NCGC00018221-08      1  1.7889   3.200163   81.6449   38.198723
27    NCGC00257404-01      0  0.4681   0.219118   48.5267   25.783516
28    NCGC00024595-08      0  0.9066   0.821924   97.5488   59.376583
29    NCGC00095099-05      3 -2.8747   8.263900  165.3811   92.940134
...               ...    ...     ...        ...       ...         ...
7692  NCGC00024309-17      0  1.1271   1.270354  123.3780   64.364618
7693  NCGC00092377-04      0  1.2781   1.633540  127.4281   65.573446
7694  NCGC00249894-01      2  0.9889   0.977923   93.7563   48.803895
7695  NCGC00258493-01      0  3.6334  13.201596   60.1071   25.220379
7696  NCGC00092328-02      1  0.9264   0.858217  117.7120   63.380618
7697  NCGC00015496-08      0 -3.4028  11.579048   55.2510   43.323790
7698  NCGC00255845-01      0     NaN        NaN       NaN  197.835924
7699  NCGC00255892-01      0  0.4437   0.196870   77.3472   40.541895
7700  NCGC00257628-01      0  2.3992   5.756161   30.7638   13.573586
7701  NCGC00095795-06      0  1.7370   3.017169   62.7555   28.529551
7702  NCGC00259502-01      0  1.7456   3.047119   67.2834   32.485516
7703  NCGC00254185-01      0  1.9464   3.788473   46.7099   19.902379
7704  NCGC00254078-01      0  1.9464   3.788473   46.7099   19.902379
7705  NCGC00259798-01      0  0.7592   0.576385   30.1050   14.373965
7706  NCGC00255984-01      0  4.3541  18.958187   97.1672   47.655895
7707  NCGC00258735-01      0  2.2459   5.044067   86.0636   43.796688
7708  NCGC00257478-01      0  5.1368  26.386714   95.2848   52.536618
7709  NCGC00163355-05      0 -0.2722   0.074093   84.3928   38.631930
7710  NCGC00254263-01      0     NaN        NaN       NaN   47.128758
7711  NCGC00260266-01      0  0.9368   0.877594   35.3574   21.567930
7712  NCGC00258239-01      0  2.3709   5.621167   75.0245   37.339102
7713  NCGC00257750-01      0  0.5695   0.324330   49.8130   25.248758
7714  NCGC00256348-01      0  0.2874   0.082599   41.9237   19.847551
7715  NCGC00254098-01      0  1.5354   2.357453   61.0800   33.663102
7716  NCGC00015563-13      0  1.6130   2.601769   97.3830   51.643032
7717  NCGC00258606-01      0  0.8041   0.646577   26.4598   15.491551
7718  NCGC00254798-01      0 -1.2646   1.599213   86.3007   41.545516
7719  NCGC00092310-06      0 -1.8789   3.530265   96.8643   57.331411
7720  NCGC00022043-06      0  0.6243   0.389750  102.7615   65.025376
7721  NCGC00257951-01      0 -0.2697   0.072738  142.9587   88.813306

      naAromAtom  nAromBond  nAtom  nHeavyAtom   ...    TDB1r  TDB2r  TDB3r  \
0              0          0      8           7   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
1              0          0     24          10   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
2              0          0     21           9   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
3              0          0     48          20   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
4              0          0     15           5   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
5              0          0     32          20   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
6              0          0     38          20   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7              0          0     24          12   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
8              0          0     25          11   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
9              0          0     22          10   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
10             0          0     27          11   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
11             0          0     24          12   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
12             0          0     34          17   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
13             0          0     12           6   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
14             0          0     43          23   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
15             0          0     38          18   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
16             0          0     42          22   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
17             0          0     32          12   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
18             0          0     24          12   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
19             0          0     19           9   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
20             0          0     36          14   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
21             0          0     31          10   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
22             0          0     21           9   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
23             0          0     45          22   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
24             0          0     12           7   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
25             0          0     24          12   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
26             0          0     30          19   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
27             0          0     22          10   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
28             0          0     55          24   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
29             0          0     84          46   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
...          ...        ...    ...         ...   ...      ...    ...    ...
7692           0          0     55          29   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7693           0          0     53          31   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7694           0          0     40          25   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7695           0          0     15          12   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7696           0          0     54          28   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7697           0          0     44          14   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7698           0          0    151          83   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7699           0          0     33          18   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7700           0          0      8           6   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7701           0          0     21          14   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7702           0          0     27          15   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7703           0          0     13          10   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7704           0          0     13          10   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7705           0          0     11           6   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7706           0          0     34          19   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7707           0          0     37          21   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7708           0          0     46          20   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7709           0          0     30          20   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7710           0          0     20          14   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7711           0          0     17           7   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7712           0          0     31          17   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7713           0          0     21          15   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7714           0          0     16           9   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7715           0          0     30          16   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7716           0          0     45          21   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7717           0          0     14           7   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7718           0          0     33          21   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7719           0          0     52          25   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7720           0          0     59          27   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN
7721           0          0     79          37   ...      NaN    NaN    NaN

      TDB4r  TDB5r  TDB6r  TDB7r  TDB8r  TDB9r  TDB10r
0       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
1       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
2       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
3       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
4       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
5       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
6       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
8       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
9       NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
10      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
11      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
12      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
13      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
14      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
15      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
16      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
17      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
18      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
19      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
20      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
21      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
22      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
23      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
24      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
25      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
26      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
27      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
28      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
29      NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
...     ...    ...    ...    ...    ...    ...     ...
7692    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7693    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7694    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7695    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7696    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7697    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7698    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7699    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7700    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7701    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7702    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7703    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7704    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7705    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7706    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7707    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7708    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7709    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7710    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7711    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7712    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7713    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7714    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7715    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7716    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7717    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7718    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7719    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7720    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN
7721    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN     NaN

[7722 rows x 1338 columns]
```

Comment: Are you saying, you are getting the desired output in cmd, but while writing to csv file, its not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't get exactly what you are asking for, but if 'Nan' values in your DFS is the problem, then try this...

In your code:

```
a=a.dropna(axis=1,how="all")
```

The issue is with "how" parameter you are using. It takes two values any/all

```
how : {‘any’, ‘all’}
```

- `any` : if any NA values are present, drop that label
- `all` : if all values are NA, drop that label

So, try using `dataframe.dropna()`:

```
a=a.dropna()
```

---

**Update:** I tested with your files, and found that there were no records matching!

[image]

I appending two files is your requirement, it seems you are using the wrong operation ("merge" instead of "append").

Try this code:

```
a = pd.read_csv("true.csv",low_memory=False)
b = pd.read_csv("false.csv",low_memory=False)

merged = a.append(b, ignore_index=False)
merged.to_csv("out.csv", index=False)
```

after merge, you can use dropna if you want!!